# Why don't the header views that are returned from viewForHeaderInSection scroll with the rest of the table?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios

I just implemented the UITableViewDelegate::viewForHeaderInSection method to return a custom view.  However, when I run the app and load the table view, I notice that header view remains stationary while the rest of the table cells scroll underneath it.  What gives?  How do I get it to scroll with the rest of the table?

Thanks for your wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it's meant to work. The header for a section will stay at the top of the tableview to give the user a sense of which section she is currently in. Then when she scrolls further down into the second section, **that** section header scrolls into view and then eventually replaces the first section header at the top.

You can see this in the Contacts app on your phone.